# What is the best approach to create a schedule job on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Recently I moved my personal project from Heroku to AWS ElasticBeanstalk, because of Heroku's new pricing table. There, in Heroku I had a schedule job using Sidekiq which was dependent of a Redis and Dynno worker.

I deployed my project at AWS, without the scheduled job, now I am facing some problems to create this cronjov at AWS.

What I've tried?

1. Create a cron job at my EC2 enviroment using a cron.config on the zip .ebextensions - I can even run some simple cronjobs, but I couldn't run a Ruby on Rails script because some configuration that is necessary and the documentation is not clear.
2. Tried to use the the active-elastic-job gem, but it raises a lot of gem problems, which makes it impossible to be deployed
3. Tried to use AWS Lambda, but I did not understand how to do it, saw many examples in Python and other languages, but not in Ruby

What do you suggest me to do?

My next approach would be to use create a cronjob in my EC2 instance with a http request to a controller containing the task I need ...

Comment: If you can create a container of your Job, then the easiet way would be to create  ECS scheduled tasks.  Go for ECS fargate to make it serverless and cost effective. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html

Comment: Okay friend, thanks for the tip, I will check it out!

Comment: Take a look at [EventBridge Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events.html).  There are multiple ways to receive the event - System Manager Run may be close to what you want but there are multiple others.  I use them to send a JSON packet to indicate what my code should do.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem. It works fine with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and its EC2 instances.